# I need to create a unique record for more than one each repetitive elements from the below input xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a unique record for each repetitive elements for `<Project>`, `<Skill>`, `<training>`, `<duration>`, `<ProjectTitle>`, `<Description>`, `<Tools>` and `<Tools_Rating>`.

I tried with my known options in XSLT and I am not getting a right result. Could you please help me in generating XSLT for the below input XML.

Input Xml:

```
<root>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>abc</Project>
<Skill>java</Skill>
<Project>def</Project>
<Skill>unix</Skill>
<Project>efg</Project>
<Skill>xml</Skill>
<Project>pqr</Project>
<Skill>sql</Skill>
<Project>xyz</Project>
<Skill>Analytics</Skill>
<Training>Unix</Training>
<Duration>30 minutes</Duration>
<Training>Xml</Training>
<Duration>50 minutes</Duration>
<Training>Java</Training>
<Duration>45 minutes</Duration>
<Training>sql</Training>
<Duration>15 minutes</Duration>
<Training>Analytics</Training>
<Duration>30 minutes</Duration>
<ProjectTitle>abc</ProjectTitle>
<Description>adafdahf</Description>
<ProjectTitle>def</ProjectTitle>
<Description>jhiuhghs</Description>
<ProjectTitle>efg</ProjectTitle>
<Description>hweuiywu</Description>
<ProjectTitle>xyz</ProjectTitle>
<Description>jgdghoh</Description>
<Tools>bcd</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>4<Tools_Rating>
<Tools>ght</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>3<Tools_Rating>
<Tools>fed</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>2<Tools_Rating>
<Tools>pqr</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>4<Tools_Rating>
</Record>
</root>
```

Output Xml:

```
<root>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>abc</Project>
<Skill>java</Skill>
</Record>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>def</Project>
<Skill>unix</Skill>
<Training>Unix</Training>
<Duration>30 minutes</Duration>
<ProjectTitle>abc</ProjectTitle>
<Description>adafdahf</Description>
<Tools>bcd</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>4<Tools_Rating>
</Record>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>efg</Project>
<Skill>xml</Skill>
<Training>Xml</Training>
<Duration>50 minutes</Duration>
<ProjectTitle>def</ProjectTitle>
<Description>jhiuhghs</Description>
<Tools>ght</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>3<Tools_Rating>
</Record>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>pqr</Project>
<Skill>sql</Skill>
<Training>Java</Training>
<Duration>45 minutes</Duration>
<ProjectTitle>efg</ProjectTitle>
<Description>hweuiywu</Description>
<Tools>fed</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>2<Tools_Rating>
</Record>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>xyz</Project>
<Skill>Analytics</Skill>
<Training>sql</Training>
<Duration>15 minutes</Duration>
<ProjectTitle>xyz</ProjectTitle>
<Description>jgdghoh</Description>
<Tools>pqr</Tools>
<Tools_Rating>4<Tools_Rating>
</Record>
</root>
```

Used XSLT: but unable to get the ouput xml.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/Record/Project">
        <Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::Project or self::Skill or self::Training or self::Duration or self::ProjectTitle or self::Decription or self::Tools or self::Tools_Rating)]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::Skill[1] | following-sibling::Duration[1] | following-sibling::Decription[1] | following-sibling::Tools_Rating[1]"/>
        </Record>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
```

There is no connectivity between these set of question and answers. I want these set question values to display the first records in one line and so on.

Example :

```
<record>
<qid>
<First set of first question>
<First set of firstanswer>
<second set of first question>
<second set of first answer>
.....
.....
....
</Record>
```

similiar to more set of qustion arrived means , i need to all create records for first question of all sets and second records to second question of all sets. Please help to solve this problem and also i m new to this xslt.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide a XSLT with what you have tried so far, also notice this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide the XSLT code you've already set up; indicate what you're stuck with.

Comment: The logic which needs to applied here is not clear at all. What determines which training and which tool goes with each project?